# Uploading in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm going through the O'Reilly book Learning PHP & MySQL 2nd ed. by Michele Davis & Jon Phillips.

I'm stuck on example 11-28. The goal is to upload a picture and move it from `/tmp` to an uploads folder if it meets certain conditions: file size, type, and whether or not it was uploaded. This is being stored on my home Ubuntu server.

The form is [here](http://lunaz.homelinux.net/learn_php/up_urs.php), and the code is [here](http://lunaz.homelinux.net/learn_php/up_urs.txt). Having a hard time getting it to show up.

When I hit the submit button w/o there being a file in the file box, I get the following warning:

`Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home/luna/public_html/learn_php/up_urs.php on line 10`

When I submit a file bigger than `maxsize` I get my error message:

```
Error. File must be less than 28480 bytes.
```

When I submit a file of the wrong type I get my error message:

```
You may only upload .gif & .jpg files.
```

When I submit a file that's the right type & size I get the following warning and my OK message:

`Warning: move_uploaded_file(learn_php/uploads/) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/luna/public_html/learn_php/up_urs.php on line 21`

`Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/php4Mhykl' to 'learn_php/uploads/' in /home/luna/public_html/learn_php/up_urs.php on line 21
Thanks for your upload.`

What I've tried:

- I thought the problem was permissions but changing the directory `learn_php` to 777 made no difference so I changed it back to 755.
- Changing the path from "uploads" to `/home/luna/public_html/learn_php/uploads`
- Using `getcwd()` before & after the unlink & `move_uploaded_file` commands but that only told me I was in `learn_php...`
- I tried uncommenting `//print_r($_FILES);` but that didn't show me anything after pressing submit.

Not sure what to look for now. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Please include the upload handling source code--Like, the code that calls `move_uploaded_file()` etc.

Comment: The folder "uploads" doesn't exist. I got a 404. Create it and it should work. http://lunaz.homelinux.net/learn_php/uploads

Comment: @Ben, post that as an answer and I'd upvote you!

Comment: Your links are broken. If you still have the source code for the form, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The first error you see is because you are trying to unlink a file that doesn't exist on line 10. After you do the `is_uploaded_file()` check you should do a quick `if ( isset($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']) )` before doing the unlink.

The last two warnings are because it seems you don't have the upload directory already created. I don't think `move_uploaded_file()` will create it for you. So just create that directory and make sure that it has proper permissions to be written to.

As a beginner, I would also recommend checking the return values of these functions so that you don't return 'all good' when things have actually failed for some reason. Start putting in code like `if ( !move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], "/path/to/learn_php/uploads/".$_files['upload_file']['name']) ) { $error = "Could not move the file to the uploads directory."; } else { print "All good, thanks for the upload."; exit(); }`

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719354/php-image-resize-script-help/1739128#1739128). That will give you a function to find the current root directory, which you can use as a prefix for file uploads and image manipulation.

Then, before running unlink, do an is_file() check first (and before moving it, you could run it to to ensure it exists in tmp if you are paranoid)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than guessing your code path try working down from the top.

```
$uploadpath=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\learn_php\uploads\';
```

I might be wrong, since you didnt post your source, but you are missing a slash in front of a directory, so it may be trying to store it in `\learn_php\learn_php\uploads\` which wont exist, since the PHP file is already in that directory, so it is attempting to access a sub directory.

if all else fails, you will probably want to brush up on the docs.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: move_uploaded_file()
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable
>   to move '/tmp/php4Mhykl' to
>   'learn_php/uploads/' in
>   /home/luna/public_html/learn_php/up_urs.php
>   on line 21

This is telling you that the folder you are trying to move to (learn_php/uploads/) doesn't exist. Double check that you've created that folder on your server.